# Wire type for under floor heat film

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am preparing to install under floor heating film.  The instructions say: Type UF single conductor or equivalent.  I have THWN-2 wire, would anyone consider that equivalent, or can you think of a reason I would not want to use it?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of room is the floor under?

Comment: It is a bathroom, but this is going under the subfloor between the joists.  The room has ceramic tile and underlayment, etc.   It is the Calorique Warm Floor.